# Unable to create JWE with node-jose and A256GCM algorithm

Tags: node.js, security, jwt, jwe

I'm trying to use [node-jose](https://github.com/cisco/node-jose) to create a JWE. I don't know why I am unable to create a JWE token with A256GCM algorithm. I have a code that works, but as soon as I uncomment the algorithm specification line `alg: 'A256GCM'`, it stops working. How could I fix this?

This is a working code with a problematic line commented out:

```
jose.JWK.asKeyStore([{
    kid: 'mykey',
    kty: 'oct',
    k: '5A611871C939AB2432F0C0552315429D787DF69F7321B4810ED2E4363FF4A036',
    //alg: 'A256GCM',
    use: 'enc'
}]).then(ks => {
    var key = ks.get('mykey');
    jose.JWE.createEncrypt({
        format: 'compact'
    }, {
        key: key,
        header: {
            alg: 'dir'
        }
    }).update("proba").final().then(ejwt => {
        console.log(`ejwt = ${ejwt}`)
        jose.JWE.createDecrypt(ks.get('mykey')).decrypt(ejwt).then(djwt => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(djwt, null, "    "))
        })
    })
})
```

The error message says:

```
unsupported algorithm
```

Comment: Please add the error messages.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add it. The error message says : unsupported algorithm

Comment: In the header, you only specify the key encryption algorithm (`alg: 'dir'`) but no content encryption algorithm (`enc` header parameter).